# laravel:image file, unlink( public_path() ) not working and show permission denied

Tags: laravel, unlink

My code is here:

```
 if(Input::hasFile('image'))
    {

        if (File::exists(public_path("user_images/{$users[0]->image}"))) 
        { 
          // delete image from folder
          unlink(public_path("user_images/{$users[0]->image}"));
        }
        $file = Input::file('image');
        $name = time(). '_' . str_random(20). '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file = $file->move(('user_images'), $name);
        $uUpdate = User::updUserProImg($userId,$name);
    }
```

Error :

> unlink(E:\xampp\htdocs\o2schools\public\user_images/): Permission
>   denied

How can I solve it?

Comment: Make sure you have the proper delete permissions enabled on the folder you wish to delete from.

Comment: But I use windows , is here need folder permission?

Comment: yes. Also make sure to apply the permission to the correct user or users.

Comment: Did u get ever resolve this? If yes, kindly explain your solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use Storage::delete($filePath)